# Migrating to Meteor/React

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, reactjs, meteor

Does anyone know of any resources available for Meteor that can help load large (20MB-80MB) assets for (mainly) offline use?

My current development is completely in Vanilla JS (on the client side) and I'm considering building a Meteor/React version for performance and for practice.  Currently my app operates both online and offline and syncs data when a connection is present with a MongoDB database.  It also initially dynamically loads large assets into IndexedDB for offline use (actually the view layer only communicates with the local database).  The whole system uses WebSockets to transport all data aside from the initial load.  The transportation of the large assets is loaded steadily through the socket so it takes a while, but that data can be downloaded and paused and restarted essentially.

Is there something out there that handles something like this already?  Or is there a better way to download large data files and install them in a local database?  It could be a JSON file, but my fear of doing something like that it would crash the user's browser trying to load all that data at once.  Any direction or advice would be much appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: I think what you want is explained perfectly in this youtube video Google I/0 2016 `Building offline-first Progressive Web Apps` https://youtu.be/cmGr0RszHc8?list=PLyHVYmk4Ww8hUrHgbtLVTNmkT1jFlSOOE

Comment: Thanks for introducing this video to me.  Its very interesting.  I have already implemented service workers to handle the initial caching of the html, css, js, and images.  The thing I don't like about them is that they just like to end when they feel like it.  Instead, I rely on websockets to keep the connection open and I use webworkers to handle the processing of large data into the local database for both initial assets and while syncing.

Answer (score 3):

As what I can understand, you are trying to build a web application that could works offline. In that case, [Progressive Web App (PWA)](https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/) is the thing you should look for.

In fact PWA is a standard, working offline is one of the core features. In practice, PWA makes use of [service worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API) to cache your static assets in browser and use them for future loads. But keep in mind that this technology is still new and has not yet been a standard for web development, so you should check if it works on your users' browsers.

Speaking about Meteor, there are already some attempts to make Meteor apps work offline. The best two which I know are [meteor-service-worker](https://github.com/NitroBAY/meteor-service-worker) and [GroundDB](https://github.com/GroundMeteor/db). The first helps your cache the app source in browser and the last helps your db live in client-side. They are all good packages, however I think they are not mature yet so think twice before using them.

Comment: I'm not sure if my app would fully qualify for a PWA.  It is not mobile friendly and initial installs of the software take between 15 and 45 minutes depending on project settings (the software can still be used, just not offline right away).  I've looked into GroundDB, but I can't find a whole lot of useful information out there.  I'm mainly curious how something like GroundDB would be like handling large amounts of data.  Do you know of any testing done on GroundDB?

Comment: You do not need to implement all PWA features for your app, because they are not needed just focus on caching for working offline is enough. About GroundDB, I do not know any real-life examples app using it.

Comment: I see.  I'm certainly interested in the info on it from Google.  I'll go through it as all of it does apply to what I am doing.

Comment: just wondering why don't simply use http://electron.atom.io/, If you app take around 15m to 45 to install is clearly not a regular app and you have control of a lot of the environment wouldn't make more sense transform that app to an desktop app?

Comment: Interesting.  I've never heard of it, but it looks like a pretty awesome idea.  It might be better for what I am trying to do.  I'll definitely have to check it out.  Thanks.